# pthread_create b/w fork and exec

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, exec, fork

I wish to create a thread in a child process before the respective child process changes it's image using exec system call. However, seemingly, the pthread_create call is being overlooked.

```
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attribute;

    pthread_attr_init(&attribute);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attribute, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

pid_t cid = fork();

if(cid == 0)        //CHILD Process
{
    switch(x->option)
    {
        case 1:     pthread_create(&thread, &attribute, compressShow, NULL);                
                    execl("/home/aamir/Lab/ass3/compression", "compression", source, destination, NULL); 
                    cout<<"Execution failed."<<endl; break; //This segment will execute if exec fails.
    }

else            //PARENT Process
{
    wait(0);        //Prevents termination of original main until forked exec completes execution
    pthread_cancel(thread);
}
```

The thread is basically just a progress display that is intended to output '.' (dots) in concurrence with the forked child.

If I remove the exec call the thread does execute. I've searched on google and read somewhere that you cannot use pthread_create between a fork and exec, something to do with async safe functions. Can you please help?

Comment: Each process has by definition its own set of threads and its own address space. So the parent won't see the thread created by the child.

Comment: One possible solution I see is to create the thread in the parent, before fork. Is there any other possible work around?

Comment: Yes, create the threads in the parent. Also create a `pipe`. Have the child write on the pipe, and the thread in the parent read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exec bit zapps everything including threads and just starts a new process. That includes memory etc.

The program might (and usually) does not get to the bit to fire up the thread.

Comment: This is true, but don't explain the mistake. Threads are specific to process. See my comment in the question.

Comment: But the exec call is AFTER the thread. Shouldn't technically the thread be created and then exec zapps everything?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I was using the KISS principle.

Comment: Oh wait. So even if the thread IS created BEFORE the exec system call, the new program will zapp it? 
How can I work around this?

Comment: I can create the thread in the parent before fork. Is there anyother possible workaround, one that lets me create the thread AND RUN/SUSTAIN IT, from the child, even after exec?

Comment: @AmiKhaon: any `execve` (called by `exec`) will entirely zap all the address space and process. Read the `execve(2)` man page & the http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ book